# How to detect active video card and retrieve hardware ids?

Tags: hardware, inno-setup, detection

I'd like to make a driver installer and I need to detect the active VGA card and retrive hardware ids.
I used *devcon64* and save the output to a txt file, but it saves values like this:

> devcon64 listclass display > display.txt:
>
> Listing 1 device(s) for setup class "Display" . PCI\VEN_...: Videocard
>   Name

I just only need the *PCI/VEN* part.

Comment: I would use WMI for this (you can consume it in Inno Setup if your installer is made by it). Besides, if you're targeting Inno Setup, include the [tag:inno-setup] tag in your question, please.